# What options are available for non-payment shopping carts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkout

We're building a website using ASP.NET C#, and we're having a problem with the shopping cart. Our users will not be purchasing anything, so there's no need to enter any payment information. The site is for a library, and the items will just be put on hold for the user. So we want the functionality of a checkout page and shopping cart in the sense that the user puts things in the cart, and when they're done, they can confirm everything on the "checkout" page. The website uses user accounts to identify the user and grant them access to do this.

Is there an ideal way to do this?

Comment: This seems quite broad. I'd recommend doing some research first.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to simply save the books they have in their cart to a session variable (maybe a List or some such). When they click "Add To Cart" simply update the value. When you get to a check out page - enumerate the list. Once they select "Checkout", set the database values and then clear the session variable.

The one issue with this is if people put an item in their cart, and someone else does the same - who gets the item on hold? You could add in code that locks the book in the database when they add it to their cart (and unlock it later - maybe when the session expires, or after a preset amount of time). You could do a check when they attempt to put it on hold (and say something like "You've got 2 books on hold, but one was claimed by someone else" or whatever.

This may or may not be an issue for you..